# how to trigger spring batch from spring integration java dsl Integration file poller integrationflows

Tags: spring, file, spring-integration, spring-batch, poller

How to trigger a spring batch job from a spring integration, using java dsl Integrationflows.

I have the below code which polls for a file in a directory , the moment a new file is added to the directory , a message is generated , i want to trigger a spring batch job at that instance. Please advice.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                              @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll,
                                              TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                              MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource,
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
              .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                     .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL)                 

             .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is clean sample in the Spring Batch [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#springBatchIntegration) on the matter:

```
@Bean
public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest() {
    FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(personJob());
    return fileMessageToJobRequest;
}

@Bean
public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
    JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);

    return jobLaunchingGateway;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("/tmp/myfiles")).
                    filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv")),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))).
            handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()).
            handle(jobLaunchingGateway).
            log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload").
            get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , i am getting  the error "The method handle(MessageHandlerSpec<?,? extends MessageHandler>) in the type IntegrationFlowDefinition<IntegrationFlowBuilder> is not applicable for the arguments (FileMessageToJobRequest)" for  handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()). Please advice.

Comment: OK. Try this then `handle(fileMessageToJobRequest(), "toRequest")`

Comment: I tried handle(fileMessageToJobRequest(), "toRequest"), it's throwing "The method handle(String, String) in the type IntegrationFlowDefinition<IntegrationFlowBuilder> is not applicable for the arguments (FileMessageToJobRequest, String)"

Comment: And what is it throwing, please ?

Comment: it's throwing "The method handle(String, String) in the type IntegrationFlowDefinition<IntegrationFlowBuilder> is not applicable for the arguments (FileMessageToJobRequest, String)"

Comment: What Spring Integration Java DSL version do you use?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: That's too old. Try the latest `1.2.3`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/releases

Comment: Thanks , that got fixed. But i am getting the below error when trying to run the application:-  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundFileIntegration' defined in class path resource [com/porterhead/integration/file/FilePollingIntegrationFlow.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Any idea why?

Comment: @Bean
    public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest() {
        FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
        fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
      //  fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(personJob());
        return fileMessageToJobRequest;
    } , i debugged and saw fileMessageToJobRequest is returning null, what should i put in personJob()? Any idea?

Comment: Not sure. That must return `JobLaunchRequest`. See the same reference manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

Comment: That got fixed , please let me know , when i am putting say 5 files in a directory , 5 messages gets generated by the poller , i want that the spring  batch job will get triggered only one time, not five times , is it possible?

Comment: ??? The task we discuss here is exactly about "job per file". Anyway that is already sounds like a different question. Isn't it? If we have fixed this one, that's great. Let's accept the answer to help other people and move on to the next subject!

Answer (score 0):

The below is my code:-

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                              @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll,
                                              TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                              MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource,
                                              JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource,
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
              .handle(fileMessageToJobRequest(),"toRequest")
                       .handle(jobLaunchingGateway)
                        .log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload")
                             .get();
}
@Bean
public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest() {
    FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
    fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
  //  fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(personJob());
    return fileMessageToJobRequest;
}

@Bean
public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
  //  simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
    JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);

    return jobLaunchingGateway;
}
```